# How to push prices and names both arrays into a single array with key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have two arrays prices and names how to push these two arrays to get below output:

```
 var prices = [];
 var names = [];
 $("ul li ").find(".checkedId:checked").each(function(index, item) {
 prices.push($(this).closest('li').find(".cal_total").val(
 names.push($(this).closest('li').find('label').text());
 });
```

How to push prices and names both arrays into a single array with key value pair. I want output
something like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 500
            [name] => cat 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 300
            [name] => cat 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense. Please may you use standard JS syntax?

Comment: Can be done very simply using map(). Please provide some sample html as per [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a single array and push objects with name and price:

```js
var items = [];
$("ul li ").find(".checkedId:checked").each(function(index, item) {
  items.push({
    price: $(this).closest('li').find(".cal_total").val(),
    name: $(this).closest('li').find('label').text()
  });
});
```